# Bash from scratch --again

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, posix-compliant

As my journey through Bash goes on, I'm still stuck on ridiculous stuff such as this script I just can't wrap my head around on:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -gt 100 ]
then
   echo "You typed a larger number"
   if (( $1 % 2 == 0 ))
   then
      echo "And it's even an even number"
fi
```

Recently I was recommended to keep ShellCheck at hand's reach, and so I did, but it seems like its suggestions on how to improve this script doesn't work out either. Basically when I try to run it, I always get errors like "[: !=: unary operator expected" even when I try to quote $1 into "$1", which is also recommended by ShellCheck. Could anyone help me down? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How do you run this? First of all, you cannot get the error you mention since you don't have `!=` anywhere in your script. Second, you're missing the closing `if` which means you would get yet another error. Third, you are probably running the script without an argument so `$1` is undefined. But please don't make us guess: [edit] your question and make sure you show the actual code you use, explain how you launch it and the actual errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has a syntax error; it lacks one more `fi` at the end.
Once this error is fixed, you get the "unary operator expected", because your `$1` value (the value of the first parameter of the script) is empty, and the first `if` command expects that value to be non-empty. You must call the script with some number as a parameter, like:

```
./script 150
```

Then you get the response:

```
You typed a larger number
And it's even an even number
```

If you want the script to not display error messages when called with no parameter, before using the parameter you must detect whether the parameter is empty and do something. For example you can add the following code before your first `if` command:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
   echo "Parameter required!"
   exit
fi
```